# CSS class definition doesn't work inside <g:HTML> element

Tags: gwt, gwt2, uibinder

Could you guys tell me why css class definition doesn't work in following example ?

I'm using GWT 2.4 + Chrome 17.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <ui:style>
        div.test {
            color: red;
        }
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTML>
        <div class="test">I should be red but I'm not</div>
    </g:HTML>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS classes listed in the `<ui:style>` will be obfuscated, going from `test` to `GKYSKJX` (or something similar).

Update your div to this:

```
<div class="{style.test}">Now I'm red :)</div>
```

Alternatively, you could choose to force your style to NOT obfuscate by doing this:

```
@external .test;
div.test {
    color: red;
}
```

Unless you have a good reason, I recommend sticking with the first method.

See more at [Declarative Layout with UiBinder - Hello Stylish World](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World).